# How to correctly add Room Persistence dependencies to my Jetack Compose Android app

Tags: android, dependencies, android-room, kapt, kotlin-symbol-processing

I have been struggling to add Room dependencies for a couple of days now(not proud). There is always an error no matter what i try. I am not the most experienced though.

I added the below from the Android docs site.

`val room_version = "2.5.2"

```
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

//1
// To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

//2
// To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP) (2)
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

// optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")`
```

All depencdencies can resolve except what is marked 1 & 2.
For 1, i get
`Type mismatch. Required: KaptOptions Found: String`

For 2, i get
`Unresolved reference: ksp`

I added these to my plugins from searches i did but to no avail.
`    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.21-1.0.11"
kotlin("android")

```
// Apply the Room and Kotlin Kapt plugins
kotlin("kotlin-kapt")
id("androidx.room.room-compiler")`
```

Comment: Any luck with this documentation? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-quickstart.html#make-ide-aware-of-generated-code

Comment: Note you do not need both, just one or the other

Comment: @ryankuck Yes. i did one at a time

Comment: Adding <id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.47" apply false> to my plugins has my app running now. But i don't think that's an ideal solution. Or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What properly worked was following the migration guide at
[Migrate from kapt to KSP](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp)

I used

```
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
```

Added the below to the project level build.grradle

```
plugins {
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false}
```

Added the below to the module level build.gradle

```
plugins {
id("com.google.devtools.ksp")}
```

And remove everything added for the kapt

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue 3 months ago, my solution was this:

At the top of the `build.gradle (:app)` inside `plugins`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

And then in your `dependencies`, same file

```
/* ROOM */
def roomVersion = "2.5.2" //this was 2.5.1 back then
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
```

Finally, check if Android Studio wrote a Room dependency for you before and delete it:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.5.2'
```

Documentation [is here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#kts)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your **project** `build.gradle`.
2. Add the plugin `com.google.devtools.ksp` with the correct version:

```
    ...
    plugins {
        ...
        // x.y.z must be THE SAME for all the kotlin/ksp plugins.
        // (My version is 1.9.10)
        id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version 'x.y.z' apply false
        id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version 'x.y.z' apply false
        ...
        // Choose an appropriate version from: 
        // https://github.com/google/ksp/releases
        id "com.google.devtools.ksp" version 'x.y.z-a.b.c' apply false
    }
```

3. Open your **module** `build.gradle` where you add `room` library.
4. Add `com.google.devtools.ksp` to `plugins`:

```
    plugins {
        ...
        id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
    }
```

5. Replace **kapt** by **ksp**:

```
    ...
    dependencies {
        // delete kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
        ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into issues. I can attest [the migration page google provides](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp) will help you implement it. Below are the my gradle files. Along with a link to the latest release of 'ksp' from google.

**Note**

- keep ksp("...") commented out until the build passes.
- make sure to upgrade to the latest version, google docs have not updated it, causing an error message. Latest versions found [here](https://github.com/google/ksp/releases)

Hope this helps, provided some code below, as I'm new to Android development.

**build.gradle.kts:app**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

 .....

//Step 0: Dependencies

val lifecycle_version = "2.7.0"
val arch_version = "2.2.0"
val room_version = "2.5.0"

// ViewModel
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
// LiveData
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
// KSP
implementation("com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:1.9.21-1.0.15")

implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
// To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP) ***Keep commented until build passes
// ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
```

**build.gradle.kts(project)**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.17" apply false
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "1.9.21"))
    }
}
```